# Information about Wordpress 4

Tags: wordpress-version

Are there any details on when WP 4 will be released?

Is it true it will be a fundamental re-write using considerable Ajax?

I am really interested in the following issue which is reported as included in 4.0

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14134

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Release Date:

> WordPress 4.0 is planned for <strike>August 27</strike>September 3, 2014
>
> [Source](http://wordpress.org/about/roadmap/)

WordPress 4.0 Release:

> [...] For those unaware, for WordPress, version 4.0 sounds like a
>   “big” version number but it’s just another major release for us, like
>   3.9 and 4.1, constructed over the same ~4-month release cycle. [...]
>
> [Source](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/04/30/helen-is-the-wordpress-4-0-release-lead/)

For WordPress 4.0 features follow http://make.wordpress.org
Planned features at the moment: http://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/05/09/summary-of-5-7-dev-chat-irc-log/

Comment: Do you think issue https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14134 will be included?

Comment: Well that would just be guessing. Best would be to follow the issue and maybe even helping to close it.

Comment: Can you guess if this issue will be included in 4.0 due this week? Thank you

Comment: @p.a. Well have a look at the issue linked to above and see that it isn't closed, so no.

Comment: Today? It's not out yet AFAICS?

Comment: Well there are still some hours to go for today ;) http://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/09/01/4-0-release-plan-and-827-meeting-summary/

Answer (score 0):

If by AJAX rewrites you mean significant rewriting of the wp-views shortcode system backed by Backbone and Ajax, yes, it is significantly different than 3.9.

From what I've tested, this is the most significant change as it is still a bit buggy and breaking existing code - see for example [29115](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/29115) (mostly fixed by now), renamed important constants used in TinyMCE modules that could break some plugins ([28458](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/28458), [29130](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/29130))